# Is it possible to use TTS in iOS

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

Does anyone know if it is possible to implement TTS in iOS development like in Android? Is it in a library or something? I believe I heard something about utility and TTS in iOS but I have had difficulty finding any documentation on this matter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By TTS you mean text-to-speech? (Just clarifying.)

Comment: HbashirNaij, i've been checking your project, very easy, clean and efective, the only thing i don't like is that you have to be connected to the internet to use it, i've another question, is legal to use the google's tts engine? can i release an app to the market place using this engine? kind regards.

Comment: In iOS7 there is a public API

Check this answer:
[Text to Speech Support][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462739/does-ios-provide-built-in-text-to-speech-support-or-any-class-like-nsspeechrecog/17465494#17465494

Answer (score 5, accepted):

flite TTS has been turned into an iOS library available [here](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src).

It is not too hard to implement.  Be aware that the performance that you see in the simulator is way better than on a device and you will need to budget extra for device testing.

Answer (score 5):

Check out my project, it's a really easy to use TTS that capitalizes on Google's TTS for translation services. To make it talk, just use an AVAudioPlayer to play the NSMutableData that the method passes. Check out the project [here](https://github.com/hbashirNaij/RJGoogleTTS).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean text-to-speech, there are a variety of accessibility based technologies such as VoiceOver which are discussed with the [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html).

That said, I don't believe these are available for use outside of the realms of accessibility. (i.e.: You can't use these to perform text to speech on demand as far as I'm aware.)