# Text to speech in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, text, speech

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text to speech on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone)

I am working in iPhone application, Using UITextView to enter the text from user, then i have set play button, when the user select the play button, text read from UITextView to speech.
But i didn't know this concept, How to read a text from UITextView to speech? please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839671/text-to-speech-libraries-for-iphone/12839821#12839821  .. if it help u.. then do a upvote :)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651438/is-it-possible-to-use-tts-in-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on the following sample code,

https://github.com/goelay/mycode/tree/75d2ef5284f335c31748ea61c5ff1ff3205829a4/sfoster-iphone-tts-a6502c779cd3

Comment: Yes i am worked as a iPhone developer, u